# print to console not showing number after decimal point in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am doing the quarter function in the Lubridate package:

```
> dfs <- dfs %>% 
>     mutate(YQ = quarter(Date, 
>                         type = 'year.quarter'))
```

I can see the year.qtr in my data when using the View function but when I do these script:

```
dfs %>% 
    filter(YQ == 2023.1) %>% 
    select(Date, YQ, Amount)
```

This is the data showing in my console:

```
> Date          YQ Amount 
 <date>     <dbl>  <dbl> 
 2023-03-01 2023.  15.4
```

The year shows up in the YQ column but not the quarter.  The Amount shows the cents and they are the same type of.

I have tried the options(digits = 1) too and didn't work.

Can someone please advise?  I tried google but didn't find any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to change the [pillar options](https://pillar.r-lib.org/reference/pillar_options.html)

Comment: thanks @akrun, options(pillar.sigfig = 5) works

Answer (score 1):

As @akrun commented, I needed to change the [pillar options](https://pillar.r-lib.org/reference/pillar_options.html):

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 5)
```

Comment: They're referring to a comment, so there is no answer to accept. It's perfectly valid to self-post an answer in this case.